# Calculate different values from using same jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I'v this jquery and that works fine if I have one field only:

```
  $("#desconto").focusout(function(){
    var subtotal = $('#subtotal').val();
    var desconto = $('#desconto').val();

    subtotal = subtotal.replace('.' , '');
    subtotal = parseFloat(subtotal.replace(',' , '.'));

    desconto = desconto.replace('.' , '');
    desconto = parseFloat(desconto.replace(',' , '.'));

      if(desconto > 0)
        total = (subtotal - desconto).toFixed(2);
      else
        total = subtotal.toFixed(2);

    $('#total').val(total);
    $('#totaldisabled').val(total); 

  });
```

but now I'm replicating using a while and that fields doing something like:

```
    <input disabled="disabled" style="width:150px" class="form-control" 
     name="subtotalshow" type="text" value="12.417,77" id=subtotal_22>

    <input disabled="disabled" style="width:150px" class="form-control" 
     name="subtotalshow" type="text" value="8020,07" id=subtotal_30>

<input style="width:150px" id="id_22" class="desconto" name="desconto[]" type="text">
<input style="width:150px" id="id_30" class="desconto" name="desconto[]" type="text">
```

im looking for a way to indentify what field I have to take the value to do calc, then send it back to another one like i did before but using the id or the class, like class:id_number or anything like that.

thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are looking for a way to identify element that has triggered the event.

```
 $("#desconto").focusout(function() {
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
...
}
```

should do just that.
Keyword `this` in event handler allows to access element that has triggered the event.

Comment: yes, I want to indentify the element by id, but this id is generated in my php while so change all the times, I'm looking for someway to indentify that element.

Comment: @LucasCampos the above code does just that `var id = $(this).attr('id');` and you will find element `id="id_22"` or `id="id_30"` in `var id`

Answer (score 1):

what i have understand from your requirement. You are looking for another input having same number in it's id. For this you can try the following

```
$(".desconto").focusout(function(){
    var num = $(this).attr("id").substr(3,3);

    var subtotal = $('#subtotal_'+num).val();
    var desconto = $('#id_'+num).val();

    ..................................
    ..................................

});
```

Comment: I'd leave off the second parameter in the `substr` call, as you don't necessarily know how long the numeric part of the id is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".desconto").focusout(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = id.substring(2,12);

    var subtotal = $('.subtotal'+id).val();
    var desconto = $(this).val();

    subtotal = subtotal.replace('.' , '');
    subtotal = parseFloat(subtotal.replace(',' , '.'));

    desconto = desconto.replace('.' , '');
    desconto = parseFloat(desconto.replace(',' , '.'));

      if(desconto > 0)
        total = (subtotal - desconto).toFixed(2);
      else
        total = subtotal.toFixed(2);

    $('.total'+id).val(total);
    $('.totaldisabled'+id).val(total); 

  });
```

that way worked, thanks for the help!